# Simple math issue?

Tags: java

For simplicity's sake, I've got the following method to calculate whether the number inputted is binary (only accepts 1's and 0's)

```
public static void checkBinary(int BinaryNumber) {
    String bNumber = String.valueOf(BinaryNumber);
    char[] Digits = bNumber.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < Digits.length; i++) {
        if (Digits[i] > 1) {
            System.out.println("You can't have the digit " + Digits[i]);
            System.out.println("Your number is not a binary number.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

However when I try running `checkBinary(1010);` I get the following output

```
You can't have the digit 1
Your number is not a binary number.
```

Any idea why it's counting the initial 1 as greater than 1?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: the character `'1'` has an ascii value of 49 which is greater than 1.

Comment: BTW There is 48 characters less than `'0'` so you need to check less than as well. e.g. space is 32.

Comment: replace `if (Digits[i] > 1)` with `if (Digits[i] != '0' && Digits[i] != '1')`

Comment: @PeterLawrey True, my hands were typing faster than I was thinking. Corrected it.

Comment: Your life will be easier if you follow the Java naming conventions: Classes start with a capital letter, variables do not. That's the reason the SE syntax highlighter is coloring some of your variables (e.g., `Digits`) as if it were a class.

Answer (score 4):

ASCII '1' is not the same as 1. You should be comparing:

```
if (Digits[i] > '1') {
   ...
}
```

ASCII '1' is 0x31 or 49 decimal.

EDIT: also, be aware that if the input number is negative, you will have an ASCII '-' (0x2d, dec 45) in your char array. Really, you should be comparing against '0' and '1' only, not using >

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I completely forgot that I couldn't compare characters to integers outright

Answer (score 2):

try comparing `character` with `character`, not a `number`. Changing your comparision to:

```
Digits[i] > '1'
```

Will fix this code.

`"1"` representation in ASCII code has decimal value of `49`, as presented in following table:

[image: ascii table]

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing numbers with representations of numbers. It makes no sense to ask if '0' or '1' are greater than one. '0' and '1' are digits and one is a numerical value.

Digits: '0' is a digit. '1' is a digit. "Three" is not a digit. Digits are symbols that can express a number, or part of a number, in some particular base.

Numbers: '0', "zero", and "one less than one" all mean the same thing, they're the same number. Numbers are amounts and can be represented many different ways, including by sequences of digits.

Thoroughly understanding the difference between values and representations of values is a *critical* programming skill.

Answer (score 1):

Digits[i] is char, you comparing it with 1 (as integer).

You need to you use

```
Integer.valueOf(Digits[i])
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Digits[i]` equals 49, which is greater than 1.

You're using *characters*, not *numbers*:

```
char[] Digits = bNumber.toCharArray();
```

When you compare a `char` to an `int`, the `char` is implicitly converted to an `int` using the integer value of that character.  And the integer value of `'1'` is `49`.

A simple approach would be to use characters in both sides of the comparison:

```
if (Digits[i] > '1')
```

Or maybe use the intuitive numeric value of the `char`:

```
if (Character.getNumericValue(Digits[i]) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue: `if (Digits[i] > 1)`

You are comparing `char` to an `int`. You should probably change this logic. Either compare `char` to `char` or `int` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

In java Characters equals to ASCII code, so you should change your if statement in your function like that:

```
public static void checkBinary(int BinaryNumber) {
        String bNumber = String.valueOf(BinaryNumber);

        char[] Digits = bNumber.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < Digits.length; i++) {
            if (Character.getNumericValue(Digits[i]) > 1) {
                System.out.println("You can't have the digit " + Digits[i]);
                System.out.println("Your number is not a binary number.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```